# Does Gmail support image maps?

Tags: gmail, images

I'm trying to send an image map in an email using Gmail. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible? Yes. Recommended? No.

See this [blog](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/2432/do-image-maps-work-in-html-ema/) for a rundown (albeit an old article, not much has changed since) on client support at the time of writing. Of particular interest are the comments, I have found.

The point I'm trying to make is that while you can create an image map in Gmail, the recipient may not be able to see it. You're better off slicing images, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It works if you open the image map in Firefox (using a locally saved HTML file), mark and copy the visible content on screen (not the code itself), then paste straight into your Gmail email signature editor which can be open in Chrome. Gmail ignores the HTML when the content is copied in *from* Chrome and it won't paste from Safari—it has to be from Firefox.

Comment: Interesting! If you could improve your answer with screenshots, I'm sure you will get a few upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Apperently they do according [to this blog post:](http://cantonbecker.com/work/musings/2010/gmail-now-allows-imagemaps/)

> Sometime between then and now (July
>   2010) Gmail added HTML image mapping
>   support, so those of us who are in the
>   business of designing email
>   newsletters can rejoice and take
>   advantage of this useful oldschool
>   feature.